# How does Hard Voting in Random Forests work, if the predictors are split equally in their predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, ensemble-learning

I have been reading up on **Hard voting classifier** which is stated as a *majority vote classifier*.

Suppose there are 4 predictors and they train on a data set with 2 outcomes (0 and 1). If 3 predictors predict *1* and 1 predictor predicts *0* as the results, the ensemble's prediction is ***1***. But what happens if 2 predictors predict *1* and the other 2 predict *0*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prescribed solution does not exist. You can consider the problem as a matter of convention; in such a case you can choose one class or the other. Note, however, that you would not want to do that. If you have a $50~\%$ of classifiers voting for one option and the other $50~\%$ voting for the other you should not trust the majority voting anyhow and maybe just rerun with more classifiers.